# Prove $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$

Tags: functions, continuity

Prove $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.
I have tried to use the definition to prove this. $|x-y|<\delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon $.

Comment: Well, although it's good to know the definition, I suspect people on the site are looking for a bit more effort.  What happens if you try to make sure that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$?  If you just had $\sin (1/x)$, that would be a problem, since the function alternates infinitely often between $-1$ and $1$ in any positive interval $(0, \delta)$, but by imposing an envelope $|f(x)| \leq x$, that alternation has limited scope.  Think about how that helps you limit the variation in a small neighborhood around $(x, f(x))$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: a continuous function on a closed bounded interval is uniformly continuous.

A corollary of this is that if a continuous function can be continuously extended to a closed bounded interval it's uniformly continuous.

Comment: But the function is not defined at x=0

Comment: This is called Continuous Extension Theorem: If it is possible to define values $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ at the endpoints so that the extended function $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $g$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$. See Abbot, 4.4.13. In our case we can just set $g(0)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $c>0$, $x\sin(1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[c/8,1]$ since $[c/8,1]$ is compact, this implies there exists $d>0$ such that for every $x,y\in [c/8,1]$, $\mid x-y\mid<d$ implies $\mid x\sin(1/x)-y\sin(1/y)\mid <c/4$, let $x,y\in (0,1)$ suppose that $\mid x-y\mid\leq inf(d,c/8)$ if $x,y>d/8, \mid x\sin(1/x)-y\sin(1/y)\mid <c/4$.

If $x$ or $y\leq c/8$, $\mid x\sin(1/x)-y\sin(1/y)\mid= \mid x\sin(1/x)-y\sin(1/x)+y\sin(1/x)-y\sin(1/y)\mid\leq \mid sin(1/x)\mid\mid x-y\mid+\mid y\mid\mid \sin(1/x)-\sin(1/y)\mid\leq \mid x-y\mid+2\mid y\mid<c $ since $\mid y\mid<c/4$.