# Is $f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I see how the function $f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$ is continuous at the point $0$ by the inequality of $|\sin(\alpha)| \leq 1$. But for uniformly continuous, I try to produce two sequences in $(0,1)$ which are $x_n = \frac{1}{\pi/2 + 2 \pi n}$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{3\pi/2 + 2 \pi n}$. But it turns out that $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \to 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Is there a way to show that using definition?

Comment: $f$ cannot be continuous at $0$ since it is not defined at $0$. However, it's limit at $0$ is $0$, so we can extend $f$ continuously there.

Answer (score 3):

For a proof with  definition, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543771/prove-fx-x-sin1-x-is-uniformly-continuous-on-0-1) post

Rather we use the continuous extension theroem. Define $$g(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if}\; x \in (0,1)\\\\0 & \text{if} \;x=0\\\\ \sin 1 & \text{if} \;x=1  \end{cases}$$
Then $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and so....

Comment: It needs to be shown that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$.

Comment: @Math1000 That has already been done by the OP, albeit in an imprecise language.

Comment: Thanks very much. I see what you are saying